# How to convert a list into a multi value dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a lists of lists that I want to convert into a 4 value dictionary where the first value in each list is the key. So for example the list would be:

```
[['267-10-7633', '66', '85', '74', 0], ['709-40-8165', '71', '96', '34', 0]]
```

and i want it to be

```
{"267-10-7633":[66,85,74,0], "709-40-8165", [71,96,34,0] }
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dictionary comprehension:

```
lst = [['267-10-7633', '66', '85', '74', 0], ['709-40-8165', '71', '96', '34', 0]]

{k: v for k, *v in lst}       
# {'267-10-7633': ['66', '85', '74', 0], '709-40-8165': ['71', '96', '34', 0]}
```

---

If you are on python2, seems like you can't use `*v` to unpack multiple elements:

```
{x[0]: x[1:] for x in lst}  
# {'267-10-7633': ['66', '85', '74', 0], '709-40-8165': ['71', '96', '34', 0]}
```

Didn't take care of the type conversion here. I guess you can refer to other answers as to how to do that.

Comment: According to the question, I think you should convert the strings to integer in the list. Py2 ver: `{x[0]: map(int, x[1:]) for x in lst}`.

Comment: @JRodDynamite That would open up another issue of Py2 vs Py3 where you'd need `list(map(int, x[1:]))`.

Comment: @JRodDynamite I think your comment has been a good complement to the answer, in case of python 3: `{k: list(map(int, v)) for k, *v in lst}`

Answer (score 1):

A [`dict`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) comprehension to compile the dictionary with a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) comprehension to convert the strings to `int`:

```
> lst = [['267-10-7633', '66', '85', '74', 0], ['709-40-8165', '71', '96', '34', 0]]
> {l[0]: [int(x) for x in l[1:]] for l in lst}
{'267-10-7633': [66, 85, 74, 0], '709-40-8165': [71, 96, 34, 0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple and straight forward solution.

```
lst = [['267-10-7633', '66', '85', '74', 0], ['709-40-8165', '71', '96', '34', 0]]

# create an empty dict
new_dict = {}

# iterate through the list
for item in lst:

    # key is first element in the inner list
    # value is second element in the inner list
    key = item[0]
    value = item[1:]
    new_dict[key] = value

print new_dict
```

Answer (score 0):

List comprehensions is suitable in this case

```
{element[0]: [int(x) for x in element[1:]] for element in\
    [['267-10-7633', '66', '85', '74', 0], ['709-40-8165', '71', '96', '34', 0]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach:

```
your_list = [['267-10-7633', '66', '85', '74', 0], ['709-40-8165', '71', '96', '34', 0]]

dictionary = {}
for item in your_list:
    dictionary[item[0]] = [int(i) for i in item[1:]]

print(dictionary)
```

---

With `list` and `dict` comprehension:

```
dictionary = {item[0]: [int(i) for i in item[1:]] for item in your_list}
print(dictionary)
```

---

In both cases, output:

```
{'267-10-7633': [66, 85, 74, 0], '709-40-8165': [71, 96, 34, 0]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
ll = [['267-10-7633', '66', '85', '74', 0], ['709-40-8165', '71', '96', '34', 0]]

mydict = {}
for item in ll:
  key,*values = item
  mydict[key] = values

print(mydict)
```